# How to create Python virtual environment with super user privileges

Tags: python, virtualenv

After creating Python virtual environment and activating it with:

```
sudo pip install virtualenv

virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
```

I can `pip install` locally inside of the virtual environment as well as to run other Pythons scripts still using a "local" or "virtual environment" that is defined inside of the `./venv` folder. One of the Python scripts that I want to run requires a `root` user permissions (it tries to set `os.setegid(1)`). Trying to run it raises an error asking me to run it with admin privileges. But when I add `sudo` at front of the `python my_script.py` command the virtual environment breaks and doesn't load the modules installed locally (in virtual environment). Is there a way to run the python scripts in virtual environment and yet as super user (with sudo)?

Below is the Python snippet that if executed on Linux machine will raise the `Operation not permitted` error asking for root credentials:

```
import os
os.setegid(1)
```

```
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

Comment: `sudo which python` simply points to the python executable location installed at the root level. How do I activate `venv` for root before running a command? Before what command? Can you please be more descriptive.

Comment: Also, please post a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little vague.

### If you want to copy all your user modules into venv, try this

- In user, without venv, do this in the venv folder `pip freeze > requirements.txt`
- Activate venv and do this `pip install -r requirements.txt`
  This should install all your user modules into the venv

### If you want to elevate your python script to sudo, try this

```sh
chmod 740 my_script.py
```

I am not a linux user, so I may be using the wrong chmod number, please use the appropriate one for elevating user privalage, but hope you get the gist
For chmod, see [here](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/manage-permissions)

Edit:

Try doing this in your python script

```py
os.chmod(path, mode);
```

Mode Options:

```
stat.S_ISUID − Set user ID on execution.

stat.S_ISGID − Set group ID on execution.

stat.S_ENFMT − Record locking enforced.

stat.S_ISVTX − Save text image after execution.

stat.S_IREAD − Read by owner.

stat.S_IWRITE − Write by owner.

stat.S_IEXEC − Execute by owner.

stat.S_IRWXU − Read, write, and execute by owner.

stat.S_IRUSR − Read by owner.

stat.S_IWUSR − Write by owner.

stat.S_IXUSR − Execute by owner.

stat.S_IRWXG − Read, write, and execute by group.

stat.S_IRGRP − Read by group.

stat.S_IWGRP − Write by group.

stat.S_IXGRP − Execute by group.

stat.S_IRWXO − Read, write, and execute by others.

stat.S_IROTH − Read by others.

stat.S_IWOTH − Write by others.

stat.S_IXOTH − Execute by others.
```

### Example Usage

```py
os.chmod("path_to/my_script.py", S_IXUSR);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, setting the script with `chmod 740` won't help.

Comment: `os.chmod("path_to/my_script.py", S_IXUSR);` sets the file permissions as `---x------` . Also, `S_IXUSR` is a part of `stat` module, it needs to be imported first. Lastly, Python line doesn't terminate with the semicolon - `;` at the end it will raise an Exception.